# How to solve Flutter TextField exception?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield, textformfield

I get this error while trying to put TextField inside my app:

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 858 pos 12: '!debugBuildingDirtyElements': is not true.
```

Here is a screenshot of the error. I even tried to use TextFormField but I got the same error:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: const [
                TextField(),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `Column`  with `Expanded` to get available space inside Row.

```dart
body: Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(),
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

You can check [unbounded-height/width video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI)

Answer (score 0):

`TextField` has unbounded width, so if you want to use it inside row you should give it specific size by wrapping column with Expanded.like this:

```
Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: const [
                    TextField(),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```